# Changing language of tab bar elements

Tags: iphone

we're developing an iphone application to be distributed in Spain. It contains a Tab bar, but we're not quite sure how to change More and Edit into Spanish. I'm sure there's a simple solution... anybody know a way to do it?

==== Edit 1 ====

This is how we add the tabbar. As you see, we create a tabBarItem for each button, but the More button comes automatically when there are more than 5 (as should be expected).

```
for (int i = 0; i < [buttonNames count]; i++) {
   switch (i) {
      case 1:
         viewController = [[fotos alloc] init];
         break;
      case 2:
         viewController =[[videos alloc] init];
         break;
      case 3:
         viewController =[[deportes alloc] init];
         break;
      default:
         viewController = [[MyAppViewController alloc] initWithCategory:i strCategory:[tempNames objectAtIndex:i]];
         break;
   }

   UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
   UITabBarItem *tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:[buttonNames objectAtIndex:i] image:[UIImage imageNamed:[imgNames objectAtIndex:i]] tag:i];
   nav.tabBarItem = tabBarItem;
   [controllers addObject:nav];
   [viewController release];
   [nav release];
   [tabBarItem release];
}

// Create the toolbar and add the view controllers
tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
[tabBarController setViewControllers:controllers animated:YES];
tabBarController.customizableViewControllers = controllers;
tabBarController.delegate = self;

// Set up the window
[window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

==== Solved ====

All I needed was a es.lproj directory in my project. I create a new file in XCode (File > New File... > Mac OS X / Other > Strings File), I name it Localizable.strings and save it in es.lproj. Any strings that need to be localized need to be defined in this file, but all other strings generated by the OS (the More, Edit and Done buttons in the tabBar, video controls, etc.) will be automatically translated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the built in defined types it should automagically work.  If they are your own text, you'll need to be using NSLocalizedString from the code, run genstrings from Terminal, and then provide a Spanish lproj inside your bundle.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. That's what I thought, but for some reason all those labels are in English, even though my iphone is configured in Spanish. How can I tell if we're using a "built in defined type"? See my edit, it might help! 

thanks!

Comment: You aren't using the predefined types from interface builder because you are overriding the values with your `buttonnames` array.  Check this out: http://www.stone.com/The_Cocoa_Files/Internationalize_Your_App.html  It's a bit outdated but it still applies.

Comment: hmm, actually, I'm not using IB at all... all the sections are created programmatically, but the More button doesn't change to its Spanish equivalent, even though I get Current Locale: es_ES. I've noticed that when I load a video with  

MPMoviePlayerController* theMovie=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress]];

all the controls are in English...

Any ideas?

thanks

Comment: From your comment I can't tell if you are testing on the device or the simulator.  I've had a few problems switching locale on the simulator, but it worked fine on the device.  Make sure you are testing with a device.

Comment: If you are testing with a device, anything in YOUR code needs to be localized by using NSLocolizedString and there MUST be an es_ES value defined by you in an lproj

Comment: hello again, and thanks for your help. This issue is when I compile for device (I still haven't tried changing locale on the simulator). Ok, say I have all strings localized via the Localizable.strings in en.lproj and es.lproj. When I do, I understand how all the sections in the tabbar get translated to Spanish, but the More and Edit buttons, as well as the video controls (Done, Loading Movie..., etc.) appear automatically, so I don't know what the key/value pairs would be for these. I've created the above files and dirs, but still those words appear in English...

Comment: however, if I do this:

NSArray *languages = [defaults objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];

NSString *currentLanguage = [languages objectAtIndex:0];

I get "en". Hmmm, wouldn't this be the preferred language ??

Comment: Ok, DONE!! Thanks for your help, it was much simpler than I expected :). I'll edit my question to post the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Add localized String to your project and given text in NSLOCalizedString();

also change the localized text.